# Python - Append particular numpy arrays based on value

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I am trying to find a shorter way to write some code.

I have 20 folders, each with a different value in its name (1 - 20).

In each folder there are text files with a list of numbers in them. I apply a function to each of these lists and then append a numpy list, one of 20, corresponding to the number in the folder name.

I am trying to find a way to append the correct numpy array without having to have 20 'if...else if' statements for checking the folder number.

This code feels unnecessarily long and I am hoping for a more concise way to do it.

-------- current psudocode ------

```
array_one = []
array_two = [] 

...

if folder_number == 1:
    array_one.append(list_from_folder)
elif folder_number == 2:
    array_two.append(list_from_folder)

...
```

any recommendations? (using python)

Comment: Put them in a `dict` or `list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
folder_lists = {num: [] for num in range(1, 21)}
```

This will give you a key: value mapping data structure in which the keys (e.g. 1, 2, 3, etc.) correspond to folder numbers and the values are lists that map to those keys (those folders):

```
{1: [], 2: [], 3: [], ..., 20: []}
```

Then you would say something like this:

```
for f in folders:
    folder_number = <insert folder number here>
    folder_lists[folder_number].append(list_from_folder)
```

Comment: Thanks @not_a_robot, dictionaries completely slipped my mind and are a much better way to do this!